# Is it correct to say "which is Jay"?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, questions, determiners

I've been watching the movie "King Arthur", and I heard Arthur asking "Which is X?"

Is it correct to say "Which is Jay?" instead of "Who is Jay?"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Which is Jay" and "Who is Jay" mean completely different things.

> [Of the people over there], which [one] is Jay?

vs.

> Who is [this] Jay [you speak of]?

Comment: Just to understand this, what you really are saying is that the two are correct depending on the resulting answer you were looking for?

Comment: @Billeeb: yes. When used as a question word, it's correct to use "which" even if you're asking about a person.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the King's English always correct, by definition?

Of course, Arthur, had he existed, would not have been speaking English but British -- the P-Celtic language Brythonic -- so we can blame the translator if necessary.